# What instruments are necessary to measure/determine the process that generates Saturn's internal heat?

Tags: probe, saturn, instrument, measurement, heat

I am writing a paper about a possible mission to Saturn but I am a business and Spanish student and am quite ignorant when it comes to the engineering and science behind probes and their instruments; I have had a very hard time researching this topic myself. So I have two questions, first, Why would it be important to the scientific community to send a probe to Saturn in order to figure out how exactly the planet generates its internal heat?

Second, What kind of instruments would the probe need to have in order to make these observations?

Comment: I would start by reading up on what has already been done by the Voyager and Cassini missions.  As for possible instruments, I could guess at a few but I am not an expert in that field so my guesses might be lead you astray...